# How does dim argument of "Tensor.scatter_" method in PyTorch work?

Tags: python, pytorch, arguments

Could anyone teach me why the below code uses dim=1 in the `scatter_` method? The meaning of the attached codes is for one-hot encoding. I tried to read the PyTorch document example and thought I should use `dim=0` for the desired result. However, the result has shown that `dim=1` is correct instead.

```
>>> target = torch.tensor([3, 5, 0, 2, 7, 5])
>>> target
tensor([3, 5, 0, 2, 7, 5])

>>> onehot = torch.zeros(target.shape[0], 8)
>>> onehot.scatter_(1, target.unsqueeze(1), 1.0)
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying scatter on a zero tensor `onehot` shaped `(len(target), 8)` on `dim=1` using `target` as input and `1.` as `value`. This will have the following effect on `onehot`:

```
onehot[i][target[i][j]] = 1.
```

This means for every row in `target` it will look at the unique value since `j` is always equal to `1` and use it to index the 2nd axis of `onehot`. In other words, for every row, it takes the value from `target` to position the `1.` among the columns of `onehot`.

Step by step illustration would be:

```
>>> for i in range(len(target)):
...     k = target[i] # k, depends on values of target i.e. dim=1
...     onehot[i, k] = 1
...     print(onehot)

tensor([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],  # i=0; k=3
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

tensor([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],  # i=1; k=5
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

tensor([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],  # i=2; k=0
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

tensor([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],  # i=3; k=2
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

tensor([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],  # i=4; k=7
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

tensor([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]]) # i=5; k=5
```

---

Notice that `onehot.scatter_(0, target.unsqueeze(1), 1.0)` would have produced:

```
onehot[target[i][j]][j] = 1.
```

Which is a valid operation only if you initialize `onehot` the other way around:

```
>>> onehot = torch.zeros(8, len(target))
>>> onehot.scatter_(0, target.unsqueeze(1), 1.)
tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

And you get the transpose of the other matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ivan. Your explanation helps a lot. I appreciate your time!